# Adobe Stratus - GroupSpecifier and NetStream Problems

Tags: apache-flex, flash, soundcloud-stratus, adobe-stratus

I started using Adobe Stratus yesterday and made a simple chat application. Today, I was to learn how to use the group feature.

But when I try to instantiate a GroupSpecifier variable, I get this error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: GroupSpecifier.    P2P.mxml
```

Earlier I was getting a similar error with NetStream (in place of GroupSpecifier).

I have Flex 4.1 and it's set to Flash Player 10.1.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

Comment: That's how I've got mine set up. Is the Flash Player you are running it on 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

just making sure, you did `import flash.net.GroupSpecifier;` right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download Flash Player swc file from [here](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer11.html) and add "-target-player=11" to your compiler arguments in Flash Builder.